# Extracting column or row given specific value in R

Tags: r, extract

here is my data frame structure:

```
T1 T2 T3
2   3  4
1 3.21 7
```

I want to know (a) how to extract the column position for 3.21, or extract the row position for it so that I can (b) use the output and place it in a new `df` so that it looks something like this.

```
T2   Row_location Column_Location
3.21   2                2
```

Comment: use `arr.ind = T` in `which` function.  `which(d == 3.21, arr.ind = T)` where say `d` is your dataframe will return `2,2`

Comment: Hey thank you! I appreciate the timely reply.